# What plant is this fragrant shrub/plant

Tags: identification

Have been looking for this plant ever since I was a kid and smelled it camping. Love the sweet smell and would love to plant this in my garden. Please help identify. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE. Could you provide us the continent/region?  It could be a Daphne, but I cannot recognize it. Do you have more photos? Could you give us some more information where it lives? (forest/opening, mountains?)

Comment: Information on plant height and width, plus area in the world where it's growing would also be helpful, as would a picture of the shrub from a distance so we can see its form.

Comment: I live in Texas, but have have experienced the smell in New Mexico all the way to Missouri. First time was camping, but I have smelled this in the city too when there is a breeze. It is about 2 feet tall.